# What to do when the Base SDK is missing?

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone-sdk-4.1

Hey guys, I recently updated my version of xcode and interface builder + SDK (ios 4.1) and whenever I try to open apps that I created before it says BASE SDK MISSING. What is the SDK folder? Should I just copy the SDK folder to my new Developer folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

When its missing, you right click on the project, click '**Get info**' and change the "**base sdk**" to 4.1 in the "**build**" tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apple is making the base SDK disappear when new versions are out to force developers to compile against the latest SDK which is always the best thing to do. You can still keep your app targeting older OS versions, but build against the latest.